# mvc controlling two dropdownlist to filter data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, selecteditem, selectedindex

hello everyone I want to ask a question abuout mvc dropdownlist. I am trying to filter the datas to their places or their codes while dropdowns selected index changed. I can do it when I use one dropdown but when I use more than one dropdown I cannot get the results separately.

As you see in the picture I have two dropdownlist.

[image: mvc two dropdownlist selected index]

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id,int? ddwList)
    {

        Repository<Order> _ro = new Repository<Order>();
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> _orderSelectListItem = _ro.All().AsEnumerable().Select(s => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = s.code,
            Value = s.id.ToString()
        });

        ViewData["ddOrder"] = _orderSelectListItem;

        Repository<Workshop> _rw = new Repository<Workshop>();
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> _workshopSelectListItem = _rw.All().AsEnumerable().Select(s => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = s.name,
            Value = s.id.ToString()
        });

        ViewData["ddwList"] = _workshopSelectListItem;

        Repository<ClothShipment> _rcs = new Repository<ClothShipment>();
        IEnumerable<MyClothShipment> _myClothShipment = null;

        if (id != null)
        {
            int? idOrd = _rcs.Find(w => w.orderId == id).orderId;
            //int? idWork = _rcs.Find(w => w.workshopId == id).workshopId;

            if (idOrd != null)
            {
                _myClothShipment = _rcs.All().Where(w => w.orderId == id).Select(s => new MyClothShipment
               {
                   id = s.id,
                   amount = s.amount,
                   orderName = s.order.code,
                   clothName = s.clothList.name,
                   workshopName = s.workshop.name,
                   shipDate = s.shipDate
               });
            }
            //else if(idWork != null){
            //    _myClothShipment = _rcs.All().Where(w => w.workshopId == id).Select(s => new MyClothShipment
            //    {
            //        id = s.id,
            //        amount = s.amount,
            //        orderName = s.order.code,
            //        clothName = s.clothList.name,
            //        workshopName = s.workshop.name,
            //        shipDate = s.shipDate
            //    });
            //}
        }
        else {
            _myClothShipment = _rcs.All().Select(s => new MyClothShipment
            {
                id = s.id,
                amount = s.amount,
                orderName = s.order.code,
                clothName = s.clothList.name,
                workshopName = s.workshop.name,
                shipDate = s.shipDate
            });
        }

        return View(_myClothShipment);
    }
```

my view is here

```
 <div id="sample_editable_2_length" class="dataTables_length">
                        <label>
                            @Html.DropDownList("ddwList",(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["ddwList"],"Atölye Seçiniz",new {@id="StateDropDown1", @class = "span15 chosen"})
                        </label>
                    </div>
```

my view is here

```
<div id="sample_editable_2_length" class="dataTables_length">
                        <label>
                            @Html.DropDownList("ddwList",(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["ddwList"],"Atölye Seçiniz",new {@id="StateDropDown1", @class = "span15 chosen"})
                        </label>
                    </div>

<div id="sample_editable_1_length" class="dataTables_length">
                        <label>
                            @*<select class="m-wrap small" name="sample_editable_1_length" size="1" aria-controls="sample_editable_1">

                            </select>*@
                            @Html.DropDownList("ddOrder",(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["ddOrder"],"Sipariş Kodu Seçiniz",new {@id="StateDropDown", @class = "span15 chosen"})
                        </label>
                    </div>
```

and here is my script code

```
$("#StateDropDown").change(function (e) {

            var controllerName = '@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString()';
            var actionName = '@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString()';

            var _id = $("#StateDropDown").val();
            var _url = "/" + controllerName + "/" + actionName + "/" + _id;


            window.location.href =_url 

        });

        $("#StateDropDown1").change(function (e) {

            var controllerName = '@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString()';
            var actionName = '@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString()';

            var _id = $("#StateDropDown1").val();
            var _url = "/" + controllerName + "/" + actionName + "/" + _id;


            window.location.href = _url

        });
```

I am filling the dropdowns when on page load from database and getting all the data to show with dropdowns I want to filter the data that shown... And with this code one of my dropdown works I am taking the id of selected item (Index(int? id)) in here but when I try to use both of them separately it doesnt work how can I make both of them work. What should I do ? The second parameter always comes null or if I use different parameter except "id" it is again coming null  ? and also I tried to take parameter as string but it also came null... Thank you for your helps.

Answer (score 2):

To explain what your code is doing:

When your select a value from your first select, you are passing its value to the Index method (e.g. `/Index/1`) so the value of parameter `id` is 1 but no value has been passed to parameter `ddwList` so it is null.  When you select a value from the second select you are passing its value to the index method (e.d. `/Index/5`) so the value of parameter `id` is 5 but no value has been passed to parameter `ddwList` so again it is null.

Assuming you want to display a table based on the selections of both selects, then you need to construct the url as `/Index?id=1&ddwList=5`.  Therefore, remove the change events from your selects and add a button that constructs the query in its click event.  However, the way you are doing this is reloading the whole page each time. I suggest you consider loading the table from a partial view using a `jQuery.get()` method to avoid a complete page load each time. For example

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  // Build the 2 select lists only
  return View();
}
```

Index view

```
// Add the two @Html.DropdownFor()...
<button id="LoadTable">Load Table</button>
<div id="TablePlaceholder"></div>
```

and the script

```
$('#LoadTable').click(function() {
  var id1 = // the value of the first select
  var id2 = // the value of your second select    
  $.get('@Url.Action("Table")', { id: id1, ddwList: id2 }, function(data) {
    $('#TablePlaceHolder').html(data);
  });
}
```

and the partial result

```
public ActionResult Table(int? id, int? ddwList)
{
  // Build your table view based on values of id and ddwList
  return PartialView();
}
```

Comment: first thank you for the answer. Actually I dont want to use button to trigger the events and I dont want  (/Index?id=1&ddwList=5) . My dropdowns should work separately when I change the index of one of them ı want to see the data of that option. as you see ı have 2 dropdown one is for cities for example istanbul,new york, amsterdam. and the other one is for specific order codes.

Comment: Then you will only ever post back a single value (_id in your script) so whats the point of the ddwList parameter in the action method (its will always be null)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this, you are able to use one of the drop downs at a time and that drop down successfully sends it's value to your controller while the other drop down always sends null.  If that's the case, that is working correctly with the way you made your dropdownlists with an *option label*.

As explained in the msdn documentation:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492256(v=vs.118).aspx

> *optionLabel*  Type: System.String The text for a default **empty item**.
>   This parameter can be null.

So if you want both of the drop down lists to be usable at the same time, you'll need to remove the events for .change and add a form with those dropdowns AND a submit button within to use both values at the same time.

OR

Do not use an *option label* meaning the first option of the dropDownList will be used as it's initial/default value.  Here is a link to the msdn docs showing the different ways to format the Html.DropDownList helper: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlist(v=vs.118).aspx

I hope I understood you correctly!

Comment: thank you for your answer but thats not what ı look for